# How can i call extra method that i define in anonymous class?

Tags: java, anonymous-class

My example shows i try to add some extra method to `Runnable` anonymous class, in general how can i call extra method which i create.

```
Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable()
{
    public void run()
    {
        System.out.println("Running");
    }
    // any  extra method to explain the question 
    public void a()
    {
        System.out.println("A");
    }

};
myRunnable.run();
myRunnable.a(); // is this right??
```

Comment: sory marvin, just got wrong my head arround, actually it can accessible within class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you even be able to do such a thing? your `myRunnable` object is of type `java.lang.Runnable`. It doesn't have any other methods than what already exists there. Java cannot know at runtime that the actual object which is assigned to `myRunnable` is actually your own implementation.

However, you can do something like this:

```
class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() { }
    public void myMethod() { }
}
```

And then

```
MyRunnable mr = new MyRunnable();
mr.myMethod();
```